# refresh view in adapter class android

Tags: android

i want to update textview when spinner item selection in adapter class but it show updation in wrong item's price . i have lost many time to solve this here is my code

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, arraylist.get(position).getProductUnit1());

        // Setting the array adapter containing country list to the spinner widget
        holder.tvproductBrandName.setAdapter(adapter);

        OnItemSelectedListener countrySelectedListener = new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container,
                    int position2, long id) {

                 i =Float.parseFloat(arraylist.get(position).getProductMRP1()[position2]);



                 holder.tvProductMRP.setText((arraylist.get(position).getProductMRP1()[position2]));

                holder.tvProductOriginalPrice
                .setText("Rs: "
                        + ((i -  Float.valueOf(arraylist.get(position)
                                        .getOfferValue()))*(Float.valueOf(arraylist.get(position).getProductQTY()))) + "");


                 OriginaiPrice =String.valueOf (i -  Float.valueOf(arraylist.get(position)
                        .getOfferValue()));


                appSession.setProductOriginal(OriginaiPrice);


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        };


        // Setting ItemClick Handler for Spinner Widget
        holder.tvproductBrandName.setOnItemSelectedListener(countrySelectedListener);
```

Comment: Just a bit confused there mate. Do you mean you want to change a `TextView`s value depending on the selected item of a `Spinner`? And you're trying to achieve it by putting the listener inside the `Adapter`?

Comment: yes i want to change TextViews value depending on the selected item of a Spinner

Comment: Why in the Adapter? You already have the onItemSelectedListener.

Comment: i cant get you please explain

Answer (score 0):

you can use hash map to check which position or value in spinner is selected and second hashMap to check textView value correspondence to spinner.

```
    private final HashMap<Integer, Integer> selectedSpinnerItems;
    private final HashMap<Integer, String> textViewValue;
```

Comment: i am beginner in android so do you show any example code for me

Comment: post your whole adapter source code. so i can give you exact solution what you want. because once a time my problem was the same as your and i  make it worked.

Comment: each time on getView called your spinner OnItemSelectedListener will call which change textView value of another view.

Comment: how do i send my code to you? please give me your email id

Comment: pramodmishra911@gmail.com

Comment: @TulikaKekre have you guys been able to fix the issue via email? If so, could you share the solution with us here? :)